# Cannot call PL/SQL user defined procedure

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new in PL/SQL, and I tried to define and use procedure like this:

```
create or replace procedure f()
is
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Hello world!');
END;
/ 

BEGIN
     f();
END;
/
```

However, in the call f() an error messege appears, and says "object [user name].f is invalid"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your procedure, you should see something like

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

If you type "show errors" or open the procedure in SQL Developer and compile the procedure, you'll get a list of errors.  If you do that, you'll see something like

```
SQL> sho err
Errors for PROCEDURE MY_PROC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/19     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
         following:
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior
```

This is telling you that the open and close parent that are part of your `create or replace procedure` statement are invalid.  If a procedure takes no arguments, you would omit the parenthesis in your definition

```
create or replace procedure f
is
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Hello world!');
END;
```

That should compile and should be callable from your anonymous PL/SQL block.